# Process states - blocked state

Tags: process, state, blocked

I wonder if process could stay in blocked state even if there is not any other process that want to run.
Theroticaly i guess the answer is yes ,but in practically it is not .. i'm right ?

Comment: And you think the programming language or operating system would matter to the fact how exactly the semantics of the "multi process" system are defined?!

Comment: to be honest its dosent matter for us as programmers. I just read about processes and their states and that i that question came across my mind. I searched google and i didn't found anything about that and i asked my self if anyone here, in stackOverFlow knew somthing about that..

Comment: I think you were not getting me: it might depend on such things. But well:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example: your process X is waiting for some IO to show on some socket indiscriminately.

In other words: you make some sort of `read()` call without any kind of timeout. That process will just sit there, and do nothing. No matter what other processes in that system do.

Comment: so as i said, theroticaly the answer is yes ,but in practically it is not, couse nobody will make such a thing.

Comment: In practical reality, people do all kinds of (stupid) things. You asked for a some realistic example, and **rest assured**: I have seen plenty of people doing exactly that. The default in many languages to go without a **timeout**.